# How to initialize datasource via code while retrieving password from vault?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc, datasource, hikaricp

I have a service which has app and it(integration test) modules and for integration, I deploy necessary services to argocd. When I initialize datasource via `application.yml` and set the password directly there, it works.

```
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${POSTGIS_HOST:localhost}:${POSTGIS_PORT:5433}/${POSTGIS_DB:mydb}
    username: ${POSTGIS_USER:username}
    password: ${POSTGIS_PASSWORD:password}
```

But, since I need to retrieve password from vault, I need to initialize datasource via code.

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Value(value = "${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value(value = "${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;

    @Bean
    @Primary
//    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() throws IOException {
        String password = getPostgresPasswordFromVault();
        log.info("Password retrieved! {}", password);
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url(url)
                .username(username)
                .password(password)
                .build();
    }

    private String getPostgresPasswordFromVault() throws IOException {
        // return blabla
    }
}
```

- ```
   datasource:
     url: jdbc:postgresql://${POSTGIS_HOST:localhost}:${POSTGIS_PORT:5433}/${POSTGIS_DB:mydb}
     username: ${POSTGIS_USER:username}
  ```

  ## password: ${POSTGIS_PASSWORD:password}

Code retrieves password correctly from vault, no issue there. But above initialization does not work.

When I run this code, I see this trace

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "some-ip-address", user "postgres", database "mydb", SSL encryption
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:659)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:180)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:247)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:48)
    ... 60 more
    Suppressed: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:659)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:180)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:244)
        ... 72 more
```

But like I said, if I remove DatabaseConfig class and only use application.yml with password set explicitly, it works.